# CSS: How to wrap header without pushing down text under it

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I want the paragraph text (Lorem ipsum) in these 3 columns to always be horizontally aligned at the top. However, at a certain point, the header text shrinks, causing the content underneath to be pushed down. How can I keep these paragraphs inline regardless of header text wrap?

[image]

Looks good! But when the screen shrinks...
[image]

```css
.about-columns-section {
  margin: 75px 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 75px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.about-column div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.about-column div p {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.about-column div span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
}

.about-column h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: Copperplate;
}
```

```html
<section class="about-columns-section">
  <div class="about-column">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <div><span><Icon aria-hidden="false" name="angle double right" size="small" /></span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-column">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <div><span><Icon aria-hidden="false" name="angle double right" size="small" /></span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-column">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <div><span><Icon aria-hidden="false" name="angle double right" size="small" /></span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
.about-column h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: Copperplate;    
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @HermitCrab says, you should add this first add white-space: nowrap into .about-column h1, but I will suggest you to include one more thing, to set padding and max-width in % into the .about-column, and then calibrate the correct percentage you need, see how it looks like:

```css
.about-columns-section {
  margin: 75px 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 2%;
  flex-basis: 28%;
  max-width: 28%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.about-column div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.about-column div p {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.about-column div span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
}

.about-column h1 {
border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: Copperplate;    
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<section class="about-columns-section">
  <div class="about-column">
    <h1>Foo long long long long</h1>
    <div><span><Icon aria-hidden="false" name="angle double right" size="small" /></span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-column">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <div><span><Icon aria-hidden="false" name="angle double right" size="small" /></span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-column">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <div><span><Icon aria-hidden="false" name="angle double right" size="small" /></span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```